# JHipster Mini Book Tuto fail, like other

Tags: jhipster

Trying to setup an app with JHipster. Every tutorials I follow I have errors and failures.

Whatever options I select I got errors on my project.

Following the [JHipster MiniBook](http://www.jhipster-book.com/#!/) procedure I have error like this on my IDE at start:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsy73.jpg

And when I follow the directives to page 24 and try to run

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

I got a build failed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUvJg.jpg

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I follow step by step the book, or other tutorials. Something must be wrong configured on my computer.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the error messages which are shown:

- On the first screenshot you have configured your IDE to use Java 1.6 source code. JHipster is using Java 1.8, so the lambda expressions (which are new in Java 1.8) cannot be compiled.
- On the second screenshot you have configured JHipster to use an external database. But you have not followed the documentation, which tells you to configure that external database in your application-dev.yml configuration file (and to start the database, of course!)

Comment: Weird cause 'java -version' give me java 1.8 and my structure project :

Comment: Sorry for last comment :

Weird cause 'java -version' give me java 1.8 and my structure project :
https://imgur.com/bgamc8H

For the second yes you right I miss this configuration file. First time full stack developping for me and first time with PostgreSQL. I will search more.

Merci Julien et vive Ippon ;)